# Tuleap error when add document

Tags: tuleap

We can't add document in our instance of Tuleap. Each time  we have an error.

In apache error log,  we find this error

mkdir() Permission denied in /usr/share/..../docman/include/Docman_FileStorage.class.php on line 112

I already check path and docman.inc file property

Is someone know an issu?
Thanks

Comment: I just be done after an error in the installatin this plugin?
In apache error log i can see to move the temporary loading file to /project_name/2/7/21.1?
the destination directory should not be there: /var/lib/codendi/docman/project_name/2/7/21.1?

Answer (score 1):

One potential source of this error is SELinux not being set to permissive mode. A quick way to check this is by running:

```
# setenforce 0
```

at a terminal and trying to add your document. If it works, you can make this change permanent by modifying/adding:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to the SELinux config file at `/etc/selinux/config`. HTH.

Answer (score -1):

The user the web server is running as probably doesn't have permission to write in that directory.

Comment: Hi,
I check this, but when i create the project, the web server create the header directory.

How can i check that this user have the right to create directory?